# Deploy Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET (4.5 Framework) project to Server 2012 R2 Standard

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I developed an ASP.NET project targeting .NET 4.5 in Visual Studio 2012, which is running fine on Windows Server 2008 R2. Now I want to deploy on

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
System Model:              ProLiant DL360 G5
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              2 Processor(s) Installed.
```

But according to  Microsoft website .NET Framework 4.5.1 is pre-installed with the OS. So my question is I can install lower version 4.5 Framework in Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, or do I need to upgrade the Framework 4.5 to 4.5.1? If upgrade the Framework, how can I upgrade (I have Visual Studio 2012)?

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.5.1 is an **in-place** update to .NET 4 and 4.5. This means that installing 4.5.1 replaces 4 or 4.5 (whichever is present). If your solution targets 4.5 it will run on 4.5.1. You should check the [changelog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#v451), however, to determine if any of the changes introduced affect your application.

In any case, you should check what version of the Framework is *actually* installed on the target machine rather than just assuming that it is as it appears on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 0):

According to 
[Microsoft Dot Net Download Link](http://.NET%20Framework%204.5%20is%20a%20highly%20compatible,%20in-place%20update%20to%20.NET%20Framework%204.)

> .NET Framework 4.5 is a highly compatible, in-place update to .NET Framework 4.

And It mentioned about 4.5 to 4.5.1 and even 4.6 an so on.
So it is not a problem . all version of .Net framework are compatible with new version.

But I highly recommend to update to newer version because there are many new exploit in .net 4.5 which can cause a remote code execute in your system but I'm sure that windows updating this bugs if you allow to update windows automatically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "all version of .Net framework are compatible with new version." that's not exactly accurate. There are versions of .NET which are stand-alone and can be installed side-by-side with other versions; and there are others which are in-place replacements/updates of previous versions.